# fetch data from DB and display it using stored procedure (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, controls

In asp.net(C#) i want to fetch data from a database using a stored procedure and display them in controls.  For example...

"Name" in textbox1

"contact" num in textbox2

Any help as I am new with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out some of those beginner's video series (some topics would be intermediate to advanced - find those of interest to you):

- [Data Access Videos](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-videos/)
- [Data Access Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/)

Marc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 3.5 sp1, then I suggest you try the entity framework.  You can map a stored procedure over and it will behave in code just like any other C# function (in a very broad sense).

tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Stored Procedure:**

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
/******Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetNameByID] Script Date: 11/03/2009 07:10:10******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNameByID] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@NameID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT dbo.Names.Name
    FROM dbo.MyDB
    WHERE dbo.Names.NameID=@NameID
END
```

**DALC Class:**

```
public static string GetNameByID(int nameID)
        {
            SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[1];

            parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@NameID", 
                System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 8, "nameID");
                    parameters[0].Value = nameID;

            try
            {
                return (SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(dbConnection, 
                    CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                        "GetNameByID", parameters));
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
```